# Create my own commenting/Q&A system on Ruby on Rails, or just use Disqus or Intense Debate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, disqus, intense-debate

My site requires authentication, so it has membership. I wonder if I should create my own comment system for user to discuss/comment on an article, or should just use third-party comment system like Disqus or Intense Debate, which requires seperate account (Twitter, Facebook, etc.).

In fact, it would be good if there is a guide to create my own comment system or Q&A system for users to discuss a particular article on my website. If you know of any, please lemme know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recently am working on a project where I had to weigh the same things. I eventually decided to roll my own comments.

Namely the advantage of rolling your own is that you have full control on how they work. I needed a moderation system/queue that I needed to work a specific way, for one. Second, someday I will be looking to integrate a 'community reputation' system, so that was another plus for rolling my own. Such things I don't want to leave to a third party solution outside of my control and the third parties don't always have such a flexible API to modify.

On the other hand, Disqus (or similar third party commenting systems) may be up your alley if your needs are more simple. For one, it's easy to get up and running and may be all you may really need. Accounts for it work across anything using Disqus, and that may win convenience points for your users who are sick and tired of having to sign up for a million accounts for a million websites. Disqus also has built in tools (for spam, trolls, etc) and that is also convenient.

If you go with rolling your own solution with user accounts, you can integrate things like Facebook/Twitter/etc login to make the registration process easier. But overall, like I said, depends on how fancy or complex you need the whole thing to be.

Should you roll your own, a good start is a recent Railscasts episode on the Ancestry gem http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry, it should give you a good start on building threaded comments.

Comment: I just came across [juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) it seems like a pretty good start for rolling your own comments that plays nicely with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Something in the middle :) Use the acts_as_commentable plugin :

https://github.com/jinzhu/acts_as_commentable